# Prevent Resizing in Dojo Data Grid in Xpages

Tags: xpages

I am creating a dojo data grid following Brad Balassaitis' excellent blog series.  I want to prevent the user from resizing any columns.

I know that each column needs the attribute noresize=true, but I don't know where to put that in xpages.  I have defined the width of each column using percentages, and that is working.  I just don't want the users messing with the widths I have set.  I am hoping to not have to programmtically define the grid if I can help it.  Is there an easy way to add this attribute?

Comment: You might reconsider taking away from your user the ability to adjust your grid to *their* liking. Rather add a link "reset columns" if they messed up

Comment: Stephan, I will consider that, but I am hoping to keep the interface as simple as possible.  I am finding that in order to save edits, I might have to put buttons so if I have to do that, I might also create the reset button.  Thanks as always for your expertise!  I am going to leave this open, in the hope that someone knows the answer (if there is one).